# Using lead screw with lead rod instead of two rods and lead screws

Tags: mechanical-engineering, stepper-motor, rail

It is common setup to have two lead rods that carry a platform that needs to move on linear bearing. The platform itself is controlled by a separate lead screw connected to a stepper.

I'm looking for very lightweight and small setup and wonder what kind of problems should I expect if instead of two rods + lead screw I would use one rod and a lead screw that would use as second rail for the device.

I understand that the end of the lead screw (maybe start as well) need to be put into some kind of bearing to provide structural support and accuracy.

Question:

1. What kind of problems should I expect if any? In terms of control accuracy stability, etc.
2. What kind of support recommended for such a lead screw (one bearing, two bearings) and what kind (since standard bearings for example 8mm are actually bigger than 8mm lead screw)?

Edit: It is for movement of optical system. I mostly for accurate slow movement - i.e. the speed should be constant and as accurate as possible.

Comment: That _common setup_ is a bad practice in most cases. Cheap rods and screws (sold for 3D printers etc) are usually curved, corrugated and soft, not suitable for small and precise setup. You should clarify, what are you building because there is no universal solution for all circumstances.

Comment: @Vladimir I added clarification about the purpose. For me the critical is smoothness. 

Now why is this considered a bad practice?

Comment: Leadscrew may not be your best bet. Anyway @user287001 is on the money its because of jamming. Anyway how long is the planned travel.

Comment: After the question was edited: Optical systems may not at all stand vibration during the imaging or focusing process. Stepper as an idea has something to be compensated or attenuated with serious mass and fluid friction. If you happen to design something which applies laser interference the needed  accuracy nor precision cannot be got this way. Can you possibly reveal your actual goal?

Comment: Precise optical mover is especially required to be rigid, self-aligning and gap-less mechanism. Such problems require investigation and discussion, this is not in format of this site. We can go to PM then, also, you can surf through factory mechanisms drawings and photos to see and learn, how they are made and read something about practical mechanical engineering. Problem of 2 rods+screw is that it is practically impossible to maintain parallelism and precise distance of them and such platforms either dangle or jam.

Comment: @Vladimir I mostly need accuracy of 3-5um, I'm more concerned about vibrations that stepper can create than smoothness of the movement. I can make large distance between bearing to counteract torque. But what is important I need to keep slow motion in one direction. The rest does not matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may plan something like this:

[image]

The green screw rotates and the blue block moves along the purple rod.

You may remember or be able to imagine this very real situation:

[image]

There's no screw, only the rod is in the hole of the blue block. The gravity cannot make the block to slide down, because the weight of the block generates enough torque to make the lower edge of the hole to bite the rod.

The screw can cause the same, but it also tightens the block to a tilted position which surely causes damage.

Long sleeve with rounded edges around the rod and tight tolerances may prevent the unfortunate tighted tilted position to develop, but 2 rods at the opposite sides of the screw would allow less tight tolerances and shorter sleeves.

There exists numerous single rod solutions in actuator mechanisms. Study them.

For more advanced answers insert more known data of the conditions that your system must stand and limitations, too.

Comment: What I can do is to put two linear bearing over the rod at large distance between. In fact since the object I want to traverse is round I can easily have distance between the rod and the lead screw to be the same as the distance between two bearings - so they will be far apart at least as the distance between the rod and the screw.

Thanks

Comment: So as long as the friction is low and the coefficient of friction is much lower than the ratio between the lever created between two linear beatings to the lever created by the distance between the lead screw and the rod - it should work.

I hope I got my mechanics right

Comment: And what kind of bearing need to support the lead screw?

Comment: We unfortunately have no idea of the possible stresses of your system. You should reveal what the actuator should stand.  A custom adapter between the screw and a standard ball bearing or lathing the screw is needed. But does your application really need ball bearing?

Comment: I need to support slow motion of an object with weight of about 500g. For a distance of about 70mm. Motion need to be smooth and precise. Rod can be kept steady with clamps but I assume I need to give a support to the leadscrew itself. One attached to stepper and other part of the lead screw need to be supported for rigidity.

From what I understood, also if for example lead-screw is 8mm, the actual diameter will be smaller so I can't just insert it into bearing with 8mm diameter.

Comment: What about accidental thumps and thuds? Something which works well being in a certain position on a sturdy table may well get crushed if it's for ex transported in a car. G-force spec is essential. Insert all these details to the question. BTW remove the accept sign. It pushes off more competent persons. I'm only a hobbyist. You can do it a while after I have edited the answer.

Comment: Accepting the answer and giving the bounity since you are only one who took this seriously and give some points.

Comment: Still one hobbyist grade suggestion: Check if you could scale a long movement to a short one with a sliding lever mechanism . Using it to scale down reduces also the absolute errors.

Comment: Level is too big. Absolute error is much less critical. For me the accurate speed is most critical.